# Text Stating the Domain Name Appears on Every Page... How to Get Rid of It

Tags: text

For some reason, every page on my [website](http://www.thezenapproach.com/10-ways-to-find-more-hours-in-a-day/)
has my domain name on the bottom of the page - to the right of the thumbnails. This never used to happen. I can see it in Firebug, but I still have no idea where it is coming from. 
How can I get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably coming from your related posts plugin. Can you check the settings in that?

Comment: Your site has been hacked (see the answers below). Recovering from hacks is [outside the scope of this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at your page source.  The offending area is a section of content that's being output after the closing `</html>`.  Judging from some of the links in that appended area, I'd say there a good chance you've been hacked, unless these look like yours:

```
<div style="text-indent:-9999em">
<a rel="follow" href="http://www.bigbrotheralbania6.org">Big Brother Albania 6</a>
<a rel="follow" href="http://www.oroskopos.org">Oroskopos</a>
<a rel="follow" href="http://horoskopi.shtypidites.com">horoskopi</a>
<a rel="follow" href="http://www.zoloftside-effects.org">Zoloft Side Effects</a>
<a rel="follow" href="http://www.poezidashurieshqip.com">Poezi Dashurie</a>
<a rel="follow" href="http://www.searchpdfengine.com">PDF Search Engine</a>
<a rel="follow" href="http://www.clonidinesideeffects.net">Clonidine Side Effects</a>
</div>
```

Time to restore your theme from a backup, change your passwords (admin and ftp), and possibly hire a professional to fix it if you can't manage it yourself.

Comment: [...] *unless these look like yours* [...] - Thanks for the big LOL!